# Apache 2 Configuration: Exclude URL from Rewrites

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an Apache2 Configuration that rewrites all urls to localhost:8080. I need one url for images that is not rewritten and instead serves the files from var/www/html (i.e. https://.../images -> var/www/html).

I know how do to that in nginx, but apache2 seems to to complicated for me. All efforts so far did not help, and neither did the official mod-rewrite-docs...  Here is the current config. I guess it is just two lines at the right spot...

Thanks for your help...

---

.
.
.

ServerName ---.---.---

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           http://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]

RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"

ProxyPreserveHost on

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

.
.
.

---

Comment: see examples for the [`ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass). Choose either proxypath or rewriterule with [p].

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I see where you are coming from and it makes sense to me. But I still can't get it to work. The rewrite to localhost:8080 always wins, even if I put add. proxypass directives first in the sequence. Maybe it is also more complicated due to the ssl config...